# How can I use JointJS with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor, lodash, jointjs

I am trying to run the sample app from jointjs tutorial, this is what I've got so far.

1) sampleApp.html

```
   <head>
  <title>sampleApp</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <div></div>
</template>
```

2) sampleApp.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.hello.onRendered(function () {

      var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

      var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      el: this.$('div'),
      width: 600,
      height: 200,
      model: graph,
      gridSize: 1
      });

      var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
      position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
      size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
      attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
      });

      var rect2 = rect.clone();
      rect2.translate(300);

      var link = new joint.dia.Link({
      source: { id: rect.id },
      target: { id: rect2.id }
      });

      graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

When I run this I get the following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: _.merge is not a functionjoint.dia.Cell.Backbone.Model.extend.constructor @ joint.js:3831child @ backbone.js:1408(anonymous function) @ joint.js:7436math @ joint.js:39(anonymous function) @ joint.js:44(anonymous function) @ joint.js?518ac863e9f6f1f9a755394c59ad7d562c084829:11194

AND

Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
ReferenceError: joint is not defined
    at [object Object]. (:3000/app/client/meteor:/app/client/sampleApp.js:5)

I have tried putting sampleApp.html and sampleApp.js both in project root directory and also in /client joint.js in client/

Anyone has dealt with this issue or have any idea of how to solve this ReferenceError?

EDIT: this is the content of JointJS where the Uncaught TypeError occurs:

```
// joint.dia.Cell base model.
// --------------------------

joint.dia.Cell = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // This is the same as Backbone.Model with the only difference that is uses _.merge
    // instead of just _.extend. The reason is that we want to mixin attributes set in upper classes.
    constructor: function(attributes, options) {

        var defaults;
        var attrs = attributes || {};
        this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
        this.attributes = {};
        if (options && options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
        if (options && options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
        if (defaults = _.result(this, 'defaults')) {
            //<custom code>
            // Replaced the call to _.defaults with _.merge.
            attrs = _.merge({}, defaults, attrs);
            //</custom code>
        }
        this.set(attrs, options);
        this.changed = {};
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
```

attrs = _.merge({}, defaults, attrs); is the line that throws the error

Comment: From the error message it appears Underscore isn't being loaded on the page.  jointjs seems to be using Underscore for '_.merge(...)', and doesn't find it.  That leads to 'joint' not being defined, since it failed initialization.  Is it as simple as that?

Comment: The code for _.merge(...) is part of Backbone.js which I have not touched, and I'm not sure what it is referencing to.

Comment: For future searchers, Backbone.js does indeed depend on Underscore being provided separately:.  From the docs:  "Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.7.0)."

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a dependency issue, I downgraded Backbone and Lodash via commandline when installing jointjs-all and that fixed the issue.

> meteor add mxmxmx:jointjs-all --allow-incompatible-update